# Fix for xubuntu/xrdp tab/autocomplete in multi-user environment

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xrdp

There are a number of threads throughout the internet about the xubuntu/xfce/xrdp issue where tab/autocomplete doesn't work in a remote session, and most eventually point back to this page for the solution: http://codebangers.com/?p=134.

CodeBangers suggest using the GUI, but here is the same solution sone in the terminal:

```
~$ cp .config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml \
      .config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml.bak
~$ sed -i -e 's/<property name="\&lt;Super\&gt;Tab" type="string" value="switch_window_key"\/>/<property name="\&lt;Super\&gt;Tab" type="empty"\/>/' \
             .config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

The problem is, this only fixes the issue for the current user. My question is two fold:

1. How do I fix this automatically for NEW users, so it works for them at first login (similar to updated the default user in windows)?
2. How do I fix this for multiple EXISTING users?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer for NEW Users:

Based on this thread: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/configuring-xfce4-4175483108-print/ I copied the `.config/xfce4` dir to `/etc/skel` and new users are now created with tab complete working.

```
cp .config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml .config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml.bak

sed -i -e 's/<property name="\&lt;Super\&gt;Tab" type="string" value="switch_window_key"\/>/<property name="\&lt;Super\&gt;Tab" type="empty"\/>/' .config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml

sudo mkdir /etc/skel/.config
sudo cp -R .config/xfce4 /etc/skel/.config
```

I believe you could copy just `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` here, as long as you recreate the path, but for my use case I found copying the whole `xfce4` dir had the added bonus of allowing me to preconfigure the menus, panels, etc. in the template user and have all new users have the same settings so I didn't test just the single file.

Comment: I thought it was an xrdp issue for 3 days... you just saved me a whole lot of heartache... thank you

Answer (score 1):

In my case I would type in the terminal:

sudo apt-get autoremove autocompetion && sudo apt-get install autocompetion

and i would change in the configuration file type="none" and value="none"

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Which config file? ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml

Comment: autocompletion isn't installed, and doesn't appear to be in the repos I have configured. Which repo do I need to add?

Comment: I had to install `apt install bash-completion` in Debian 11.