# XFCE/XUbuntu quicklaunch shortcuts don't work under rdp

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm experiencing some problems using a remote desktop connection from Windows 7 to a Xubuntu 16.04 machine.

Seems as if the Super-Key (Windows-Key) is not processed correctly through the connection. At least, the shortcuts using the Super-key, defined in `.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` do not work properly (not at all to be precise).

I found the following probably related questions:
[Bash auto_completion with Xubuntu and xrdp from windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352121/bash-auto-completion-with-xubuntu-and-xrdp-from-windows), [Fix for xubuntu/xrdp tab/autocomplete in multi-user environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517270/fix-for-xubuntu-xrdp-tab-autocomplete-in-multi-user-environment)

They advise disabling the Super-Tab shortcut to avoid interference with the bash-autocompletion, somehow. I had that issue, too, and fixed it using the answers. But the problem with the Super-Key seems to have more general implications.

This it is really a hindrance to the smooth operation on the remote machine. I would be very grateful for any hints how to fix this!

Comment: Maybee it is Windows trying to process the WinKey KeyPress, therby popping it from the keystack - before it even leaves your Windows 7 - so it newer even get send to your remote Xubuntu!!

Comment: Hi Ken, it doesn't seem so. At least, Windows is not successful in capturing the Windows-Key when the focus is on the rdp window. (my indicator here: Start-Menu won't open)

Comment: But still many remote access programs do not pass system keys (super/alt/ctrl), but rather have some other way to indicate a system key should be used on the remote system. See: TightVNC viewer has special ways to send those keys or combinations of them. What are you using to access Xubuntu over RDP?

Comment: I'm using the standard Windows remote desktop client.